# Making sense of INNODB buffer pool stats

Tags: mysql, innodb, buffer-pool

After having read [this page in the mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html), I tried to make sense of our current InnoDB usage. Currently, we allocate 6GB of RAM for the buffer pool. Our database size is about the same. Here's the output from `show engine innodb status\G` (we're running v5.5)

```
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total memory allocated 6593445888; in additional pool allocated 0
Dictionary memory allocated 1758417
Buffer pool size   393215
Free buffers       853
Database pages     360515
Old database pages 133060
Modified db pages  300
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 7365790, not young 23099457
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 1094342, created 185628, written 543182148
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 37.32 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 360515, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[2571]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
```

I wanted to know how well we're utilizing the buffer cache. After initially glancing at the output, it appeared that we are indeed using it, based off of the `Pages made young` and `not young` have numbers in them and `Buffer pool hit rate is 1000 / 10000` (which I saw elsewhere on the web that this means it's being used pretty heavily. True?)

What's throwing me through a loop is why the `young-making rate` and `not` are both at 0/1000 and the `young/s` and `non-young/s` accesses are both at 0. Those would all indicate that it's not being used at all, right?

Can anyone help make sense of this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
 Buffer pool hit rate is 1000 / 1000
```

This is the *only* really meaningful value in the situation that you are in... and that situation is that you are lucky enough to have a buffer pool with a perfect 100% hit rate.  Don't over-analyze the rest of it, because there is nothing you need to change, unless the server OS is low on memory, causing swapping.

The young/not young values aren't interesting in a case where there's zero pressure on the buffer pool.  InnoDB is using it, it doesn't do anything without it.  If the pool is too small, pages get evicted and new pages get read in and the other stats help you understand that... but that is  problem you don't appear to have.

Free "unused" space in the pool will *never* be neglected or left idle by InnoDB if it is needed for any reason at all, so the fact that it's free means only that you have some breathing room to expand into as the size of your working dataset grows.

That's all it means, unless, of course, you recently restarted the server, in which case, it's incomplete..  The server needs to run through a full period of "normal" usage (including full backups) before the stats tell the whole story... whether that's an hour, a day, week, month, or year, depends on your application.

Answer (score 31):

`The Buffer pool size   393215` This is in pages not bytes.

To see the Buffer Pool size in GB run this:

```
SELECT FORMAT(BufferPoolPages*PageSize/POWER(1024,3),2) BufferPoolDataGB FROM
(SELECT variable_value BufferPoolPages FROM information_schema.global_status
WHERE variable_name = 'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total') A,
(SELECT variable_value PageSize FROM information_schema.global_status
WHERE variable_name = 'Innodb_page_size') B;
```

`Database pages     360515` This is the number of pages with data inside the Buffer Pool

To see the amount of data in the Buffer Pool size in GB run this:

```
SELECT FORMAT(BufferPoolPages*PageSize/POWER(1024,3),2) BufferPoolDataGB FROM
(SELECT variable_value BufferPoolPages FROM information_schema.global_status
WHERE variable_name = 'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data') A,
(SELECT variable_value PageSize FROM information_schema.global_status
WHERE variable_name = 'Innodb_page_size') B;
```

To see the percentage of the Buffer Pool in use, run this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(FORMAT(DataPages*100.0/TotalPages,2),' %') BufferPoolDataPercentage FROM
(SELECT variable_value DataPages FROM information_schema.global_status
WHERE variable_name = 'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data') A,
(SELECT variable_value TotalPages FROM information_schema.global_status
WHERE variable_name = 'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total') B;
```

`Modified db pages  300` This is the number of pages in the Buffer Pool that have to be written back to the database. They are also referred to as dirty pages.

To see the Space Taken Up by Dirty Pages, run this:

```
SELECT FORMAT(DirtyPages*PageSize/POWER(1024,3),2) BufferPoolDirtyGB FROM
(SELECT variable_value DirtyPages FROM information_schema.global_status
WHERE variable_name = 'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty') A,
(SELECT variable_value PageSize FROM information_schema.global_status
WHERE variable_name = 'Innodb_page_size') B;
```

To see the Percentage of Dirty Pages, run this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(FORMAT(DirtyPages*100.0/TotalPages,2),' %') BufferPoolDirtyPercentage FROM
(SELECT variable_value DirtyPages FROM information_schema.global_status
WHERE variable_name = 'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty') A,
(SELECT variable_value TotalPages FROM information_schema.global_status
WHERE variable_name = 'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total') B;
```

As for the other things in the display, run this:

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Innodb_buffer_pool%';
```

You'll see all the status variables for the Buffer Pool. ou can apply the same queries against whatever you need to examine.

### UPDATE 2021-10-01 11:41

Here is a script that will work in MySQL 5.6, 5.7, and 8.0

```
SET @SCH = IF(VERSION()<'5.7','information_schema','performance_schema');

SET @SQLSTMT=CONCAT("SELECT variable_value INTO @HOSTNAME        FROM ",@SCH,".global_variables WHERE variable_name='hostname'");
PREPARE s FROM @SQLSTMT; EXECUTE s ; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;

SET @SQLSTMT=CONCAT("SELECT variable_value INTO @IBP_SIZE        FROM ",@SCH,".global_variables WHERE variable_name='innodb_buffer_pool_size'");
PREPARE s FROM @SQLSTMT; EXECUTE s ; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;

SET @SQLSTMT=CONCAT("SELECT variable_value INTO @IBP_PAGES_DATA  FROM ",@SCH,".global_status    WHERE variable_name='Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data'");
PREPARE s FROM @SQLSTMT; EXECUTE s ; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;

SET @SQLSTMT=CONCAT("SELECT variable_value INTO @IBP_PAGES_FREE  FROM ",@SCH,".global_status    WHERE variable_name='Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free'");
PREPARE s FROM @SQLSTMT; EXECUTE s ; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;

SET @SQLSTMT=CONCAT("SELECT variable_value INTO @IBP_PAGES_MISC  FROM ",@SCH,".global_status    WHERE variable_name='Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc'");
PREPARE s FROM @SQLSTMT; EXECUTE s ; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;

SET @SQLSTMT=CONCAT("SELECT variable_value INTO @IBP_PAGES_TOTAL FROM ",@SCH,".global_status    WHERE variable_name='Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total'");
PREPARE s FROM @SQLSTMT; EXECUTE s ; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;

SET @SQLSTMT=CONCAT("SELECT variable_value INTO @IBP_PAGE_SIZE   FROM ",@SCH,".global_status    WHERE variable_name='Innodb_page_size'");
PREPARE s FROM @SQLSTMT; EXECUTE s ; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;

SET @IBP_PCT_DATA = 100.00 * @IBP_PAGES_DATA / @IBP_PAGES_TOTAL;
SET @IBP_PCT_FREE = 100.00 * @IBP_PAGES_FREE / @IBP_PAGES_TOTAL;
SET @IBP_PCT_MISC = 100.00 * @IBP_PAGES_MISC / @IBP_PAGES_TOTAL;
SET @IBP_PCT_FULL = 100.00 * (@IBP_PAGES_TOTAL - @IBP_PAGES_FREE) / @IBP_PAGES_TOTAL;

SET @initpad = 19;
SET @padding = IF(LENGTH(@HOSTNAME)>@initpad,LENGTH(@HOSTNAME),@initpad);
SET @decimal_places = 5; SET @KB = 1024; SET @MB = POWER(1024,2); SET @GB = POWER(1024,3);

SELECT       'innodb_buffer_pool_size' as 'Option',LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_SIZE,0),@padding,' ') Value
UNION SELECT 'innodb_buffer_pool_size GB',LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_SIZE / @GB,0),@padding,' ');

SELECT       'Hostname' Status                ,LPAD(@HOSTNAME,@padding,' ') Value
UNION SELECT 'This Moment'                    ,NOW()
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_page_size'               ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGE_SIZE,0),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data'  ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_DATA ,0),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free'  ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_FREE ,0),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc'  ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_MISC ,0),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total' ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_TOTAL,0),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data'  ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_DATA  * @IBP_PAGE_SIZE,0),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_free'  ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_FREE  * @IBP_PAGE_SIZE,0),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_misc'  ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_MISC  * @IBP_PAGE_SIZE,0),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_total' ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_TOTAL * @IBP_PAGE_SIZE,0),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_data GB'     ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_DATA  * @IBP_PAGE_SIZE / @GB,@decimal_places),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_free KB'     ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_FREE  * @IBP_PAGE_SIZE / @KB,@decimal_places),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_free MB'     ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_FREE  * @IBP_PAGE_SIZE / @MB,@decimal_places),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_free GB'     ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_FREE  * @IBP_PAGE_SIZE / @GB,@decimal_places),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_free GB'     ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_FREE  * @IBP_PAGE_SIZE / @GB,@decimal_places),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_misc KB'     ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_MISC  * @IBP_PAGE_SIZE / @KB,@decimal_places),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_misc MB'     ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_MISC  * @IBP_PAGE_SIZE / @MB,@decimal_places),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_misc GB'     ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_MISC  * @IBP_PAGE_SIZE / @GB,@decimal_places),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_total GB'    ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_TOTAL * @IBP_PAGE_SIZE / @GB,@decimal_places),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Percentage Data'                ,LPAD(CONCAT(FORMAT(@IBP_PCT_DATA,2),' %'),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Percentage Free'                ,LPAD(CONCAT(FORMAT(@IBP_PCT_FREE,2),' %'),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Percentage Misc'                ,LPAD(CONCAT(FORMAT(@IBP_PCT_MISC,2),' %'),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Percentage Used'                ,LPAD(CONCAT(FORMAT(@IBP_PCT_FULL,2),' %'),@padding,' ')
;
```

Here is a sample output

```
$ mysql --table < ibp_review.sql 
+----------------------------+---------------------+
| Option                     | Value               |
+----------------------------+---------------------+
| innodb_buffer_pool_size    |      10,737,418,240 |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size GB |                  10 |
+----------------------------+---------------------+
+--------------------------------+---------------------+
| Status                         | Value               |
+--------------------------------+---------------------+
| Hostname                       |        somehostname |
| This Moment                    | 2021-10-01 11:35:12 |
| Innodb_page_size               |              16,384 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data  |             130,061 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free  |             524,379 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc  |                 840 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total |             655,280 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data  |       2,130,919,424 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_free  |       8,591,425,536 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_misc  |          13,762,560 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_total |      10,736,107,520 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_data GB     |             1.98457 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_free KB     |     8,390,064.00000 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_free MB     |         8,193.42188 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_free GB     |             8.00139 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_misc KB     |        13,440.00000 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_misc MB     |            13.12500 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_misc GB     |             0.01282 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_total GB    |             9.99878 |
| Percentage Data                |             19.85 % |
| Percentage Free                |             80.02 % |
| Percentage Misc                |              0.13 % |
| Percentage Used                |             19.98 % |
+--------------------------------+---------------------+
$
```

Comment: Thank you! So from this, I gather that our buffer cache is indeed being used, but what I want to know is if we're EFFECTIVELY using it. If I understand the concept of the young and old pages, my guess would be that a good indicator that the buffer cache is being used to its fullest would be in the number of pages made young and accesses to young pages, correct? We use mysqldump to do backups every 3 hours, which would explain why it's full. But with `young-making rate 0 / 1000` and `0.00 youngs/s`, that tells us we're not really utilizing it. Am I reading this right?

Comment: The young-making rate of 0 / 1000 tells you that of the data pages for the queries you are running are not only all fit into the cache, they fit into the smaller (3/8) size of the young cache. That is, the queries are not using enough data to age some of the pages into the large not-young cache.

Comment: A short explanation on remaining innodb_buffer_pool status variables will be very useful. Can you please add it to your answer

Comment: For mysql 5.7, replace information_schema.X with performance_schema.X to make the above queries work. 

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema-variable-table-migration.html

Comment: @Aakash thank you for pointing this out. I actually have a script that uses Dynamic SQL to determine which schema to read from. I will post that now.

Answer (score 6):

I'll disagree with the assessment that "you are lucky enough to have a buffer pool with a perfect 100% hit rate"

At the top of the output (which is chopped off), is a line something like:

```
Per second averages calculated from the last 16 seconds
```

This says to me that *no* reads happened in the last 16 seconds, thereby (artificially) giving you a perfect '1000/1000' score.

```
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 37.32 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
```

Meanwhile there were some writes.  These were possibly deferred writes for either flushing 'dirty' pages or cleaning up indexes from the 'change buffer'.

Probably there was no activity in the young/hot area in the last 16 seconds either.

Comment: Well, we average between 6k-10k SELECTs a second and at the same time I can see almost 0 disk read activity on the server, so I don't think this is the case

Comment: Is the "Query cache" satisfying most of the queries?  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'query%';` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Qc%';` and `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'Com_SELECT';`.

Comment: I also see 0.00 reads/s and this seems impossible. Also, if I query it twice within a few seconds, "Pages read" increases and "reads/s" remains 0.00.

Comment: @CurtisYallop - "reads" perhaps refers to fetching from disk -- as opposed to finding it cached in RAM.

Answer (score 0):

The buffer pool is divided into two part, a young list and a not-young list. The making rate shows how many pages in the buffer pools are being shuffled between the two lists.

Pages made young are not-young pages being made (i.e. being read out of the cache. Pages made not-young are pages moved from the young list because either they are too old, or because the young list is full.

The rate at pages are moved between the two depends upon how much of the buffer pool is currently being used vs the size of the young pool. Set at zero means your active set (the pages you are using) is smaller than the young pool.

Answer (score -1):

```
MySQL [(none)]> select version();
+---------------+
| version()     |
+---------------+
| 8.0.27-18-ndb |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have to modify ibp_review.sql a little as below.

```
SET @SCH = IF(VERSION()<'5.7','information_schema','performance_schema');

select CONCAT("SELECT variable_value INTO @HOSTNAME        FROM ",@SCH,".global_variables WHERE variable_name='hostname'") into @SQLSTMT;
PREPARE s FROM @SQLSTMT; EXECUTE s ; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;

select CONCAT("SELECT variable_value INTO @IBP_SIZE        FROM ",@SCH,".global_variables WHERE variable_name='innodb_buffer_pool_size'") into @SQLSTMT;
PREPARE s FROM @SQLSTMT; EXECUTE s ; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;

select CONCAT("SELECT variable_value INTO @IBP_PAGES_DATA  FROM ",@SCH,".global_status    WHERE variable_name='Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data'") into @SQLSTMT;
PREPARE s FROM @SQLSTMT; EXECUTE s ; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;

select CONCAT("SELECT variable_value INTO @IBP_PAGES_FREE  FROM ",@SCH,".global_status    WHERE variable_name='Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free'") into @SQLSTMT;
PREPARE s FROM @SQLSTMT; EXECUTE s ; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;

select CONCAT("SELECT variable_value INTO @IBP_PAGES_MISC  FROM ",@SCH,".global_status    WHERE variable_name='Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc'") into @SQLSTMT;
PREPARE s FROM @SQLSTMT; EXECUTE s ; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;

select CONCAT("SELECT variable_value INTO @IBP_PAGES_TOTAL FROM ",@SCH,".global_status    WHERE variable_name='Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total'") into @SQLSTMT;
PREPARE s FROM @SQLSTMT; EXECUTE s ; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;

select CONCAT("SELECT variable_value INTO @IBP_PAGE_SIZE   FROM ",@SCH,".global_status    WHERE variable_name='Innodb_page_size'") into @SQLSTMT;
PREPARE s FROM @SQLSTMT; EXECUTE s ; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;

SET @IBP_PCT_DATA = 100.00 * @IBP_PAGES_DATA / @IBP_PAGES_TOTAL;
SET @IBP_PCT_FREE = 100.00 * @IBP_PAGES_FREE / @IBP_PAGES_TOTAL;
SET @IBP_PCT_MISC = 100.00 * @IBP_PAGES_MISC / @IBP_PAGES_TOTAL;
SET @IBP_PCT_FULL = 100.00 * (@IBP_PAGES_TOTAL - @IBP_PAGES_FREE) / @IBP_PAGES_TOTAL;

SET @initpad = 19;
SET @padding = IF(LENGTH(@HOSTNAME)>@initpad,LENGTH(@HOSTNAME),@initpad);
SET @decimal_places = 5; SET @KB = 1024; SET @MB = POWER(1024,2); SET @GB = POWER(1024,3);

SELECT       'innodb_buffer_pool_size' as 'Option',LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_SIZE,0),@padding,' ') Value
UNION SELECT 'innodb_buffer_pool_size GB',LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_SIZE / @GB,0),@padding,' ');

SELECT       'Hostname' Status                ,LPAD(@HOSTNAME,@padding,' ') Value
UNION SELECT 'This Moment'                    ,NOW()
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_page_size'               ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGE_SIZE,0),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data'  ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_DATA ,0),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free'  ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_FREE ,0),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc'  ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_MISC ,0),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total' ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_TOTAL,0),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data'  ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_DATA  * @IBP_PAGE_SIZE,0),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_free'  ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_FREE  * @IBP_PAGE_SIZE,0),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_misc'  ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_MISC  * @IBP_PAGE_SIZE,0),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_total' ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_TOTAL * @IBP_PAGE_SIZE,0),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_data GB'     ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_DATA  * @IBP_PAGE_SIZE / @GB,@decimal_places),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_free KB'     ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_FREE  * @IBP_PAGE_SIZE / @KB,@decimal_places),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_free MB'     ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_FREE  * @IBP_PAGE_SIZE / @MB,@decimal_places),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_free GB'     ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_FREE  * @IBP_PAGE_SIZE / @GB,@decimal_places),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_free GB'     ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_FREE  * @IBP_PAGE_SIZE / @GB,@decimal_places),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_misc KB'     ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_MISC  * @IBP_PAGE_SIZE / @KB,@decimal_places),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_misc MB'     ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_MISC  * @IBP_PAGE_SIZE / @MB,@decimal_places),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_misc GB'     ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_MISC  * @IBP_PAGE_SIZE / @GB,@decimal_places),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Innodb_buffer_pool_total GB'    ,LPAD(FORMAT(@IBP_PAGES_TOTAL * @IBP_PAGE_SIZE / @GB,@decimal_places),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Percentage Data'                ,LPAD(CONCAT(FORMAT(@IBP_PCT_DATA,2),' %'),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Percentage Free'                ,LPAD(CONCAT(FORMAT(@IBP_PCT_FREE,2),' %'),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Percentage Misc'                ,LPAD(CONCAT(FORMAT(@IBP_PCT_MISC,2),' %'),@padding,' ')
UNION SELECT 'Percentage Used'                ,LPAD(CONCAT(FORMAT(@IBP_PCT_FULL,2),' %'),@padding,' ')
;
```

Comment: I am not sure how this answers the question